# Count Session rows in Laravel

Tags: php, database, session, laravel

I have this line of code in a View::make() method within a controller:

```
'playersOnline' => count(Session::all())
```

I have no user created Session class, as I believe one already exists elsewhere and has the function all() in it.

The sessions table has 1 entry, but this line of code returns 3.
All I am trying to do is get the total number of rows in this table. 
How could I change this, to achieve my goal?

Update. I now have this functional code:

```
$playersOnline = DB::table('sessions') -> select('*') -> count();
```

This returns the correct data. Now is there any problems with doing this?

Answer (score 4):

You are mixing different things:

1. A user defined Eloquent model vs. Laravel's session class.
2. Laravel's session class that access the session vs. a database query that uses a [RDBMS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Relational_database_management_system).

### Session

```
count(Session::all())
```

The `Session` class in Laravel is used to access the [PHP session](http://php.net/manual/en/book.session.php). This class has a function called `all()` that will return all data from the session, like you can see it in the [documentation](http://laravel.com/docs/4.2/session). In your code you use the [`count()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.count.php) PHP function on the result of this command.

### Database

```
DB::table('sessions')->select('*')->count();
```

Your second code is a database query made with Laravel's query builder. You select all rows from the `sessions` table in the database then you count them with your database management system, for example MySQL.

### Eloquent

With the Eloquent [ORM](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Object-relational_mapping) you can create smart models. With these you can create instances that will help you access and manipulate the database through them, with the help of Eloquent's methods like `all()` that will return all the rows of the table like model instances. Just take a look at the [documentation](http://laravel.com/docs/4.2/eloquent).

Comment: I understand things a bit better now. I think I shall stick with the query builder for now. I wish to check if a user (who is not the one logged in) has a database session running. How could I achieve this with the info you provided?